# Is there a way to make sure that all the child branches of a master also triggers a particular downstream project?

Tags: jenkins, branch, checkmarx

I have a requirement in Jenkins. Currently, I have made a feature branch of a pipeline project and made a build on Jenkins server. After the build, I am adding the source code and the build result rpm's to the artifacts on Jenkins UI. After this, I am triggering a downstream checkmark project which will copy the source code and do static code analysis on checkmarx and then display the results on Jenkins. Now I want to do the same for Master branch and all the future feature branches of the master. THis is where I need help. [image]

Currently (see picture) I have added this checkmarx project to copy the sources from the artifacts of the upstream project and then trigger the checkmarx analysis. How should I add the master and also all the future branches that may be created by different developers also to be able to trigger this downstream checkmarx project. Is there a way to specify it in the 'project name' section ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using a pipeline job, it doesn't make a lot of sense to try to chain jobs together. The whole point of a pipeline job is to create a single place where all the config for all the stages of your build/test/deploy happen.

Trigger the checkmarx analysis in the Jenkinsfile itself. To be clear, I don't mean to trigger a separate job, but actually do the work that the checkmarx job does, but in the Jenkinsfile. They it will always happen for every build of every branch that has your Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Hi Rob,Thanks for the reply. That was my original plan. But unfortunately the checkmarx software version that my company currently has is pretty old. it is 8.1.0.

Comment: For this version of software the latest version of checkmarx plugin 8.42 (which is the plugin version that supports pipeline jobs) throws an error and refuses user authentication on the checkmarx server. So the only option I had was to take an older version of plugin and do the configurations with that. The older plugins does not support pipeline methods and we are unable to generate the right pipeline scripts to put in the jenkinsfile. So now i do this workaround of creating a downstream multiconfig job and publish checkmarx results through that on Jenkins.